# $(document).ready() doesn't seem to work properly with user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jcrop

I have made a user control, and placed some code in the $(document).ready() method, but when I place breakpoints, by the boxWidth value, and step through, I can visibly see that the html has not yet loaded, and that is why I am getting undefined values. I need the html to load first, so that I can get the width and height of an img element to calculate aspect rations etc.

A screen shot is given below:

[image]

Comment: Next time please post the code itself as well.

Answer (score 5):

You simply haven't declared those variables anywhere. Try this:

```
var elem = $("#Body_Body_ucImageUploadAndCrop_CropImage"),
    boxWidth = elem.width(),
    boxHeight = elem.height();

elem.Jcrop({
    onSelect: storeCoords,
    boxWidth: boxWidth,
    boxHeight: boxHeight,
    aspectRatio: boxWidth / boxHeight
});
```

Now that your code runs error free, you might wanna access the image only after it's loaded:

```
$(window).on( "load", function() {
    //Code to run after window has loaded
});
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thats what the error in the screenshot tells atleast, nicely spotted :)

Comment: @thmsn tbh if the image is not cached he is gonna get `0` for the dimensions

Comment: I am still getting a 0 for the dimensions?

Comment: @lee no `0/0` gives `NaN`. The `ReferenceError` is because you referenced non-existent variables.

Answer (score -1):

You shall be looking for resources loaded event

```
$.load("image_id", function(){ ... });
```